# What's the purpose for having separate XML files for different platform versions in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, resources

I'm currently working on a legacy project that has various files that use the different platform versions (like v8), so I have two separate files `values-v8/strings.xml` and `values/strings.xml`.

I read that resource files appended with `-v8` or something similar indicates that it's a separate platform version, but I couldn't figure out why this is necessary.

If I were to combine these files into one, are there any adverse effects? Or is there anything I should be aware of if I were to refactor these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to combine these files into one, are there any adverse effects?

It might cause problems on API Level 7 and older devices.

Since API Level 7 is Android 2.1, I sincerely hope you are no longer supporting that version.

If your `minSdkVersion` is 8 or higher, then any strings that appear in both files are redundant, as Android will only use the `res/values-v8/strings.xml` version. So, you could merge them, picking the `-v8` ones where there are duplicates, and get the same results.

> I couldn't figure out why this is necessary

That stuff was probably written in 2011 or so. We did all sorts of strange things back then.

Comment: "We did all sorts of strange things back then." Hahahah. The good old days.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually used for `styles.xml`, to have different styles for different platform levels.
Using it for `strings.xml` seems kinda un-neccessary, and I don't see any reason one would have to do that separation.

Nevertheless we would have to see more of you project to understand why that separation was done. Perhaps you have XML layouts for different platforms that use different strings ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i agree with your answer, I'd imagine older devices work with permissions differently (no runtime request) and some features might not be available or work differently, so you'd need other strings for cases like these